# Spark in different location on master than slaves

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, master-slave, apache-spark-2.0

I had an Apache Spark setup with a master and 2 slaves. Spark was in the same location on each of the slave nodes as on master.

> ~/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

This worked fine.

I now wish to move the location of spark on the slave nodes but keep it where it is on master. Now my setup looks like this:

Master:

> ~/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Slaves:

> ~/spark/spark2/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Now when I run start-slaves.sh on my master instance I get the following error:

> slave1: bash: line 0: cd: ~/spark/spark2/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7: No
>   such file or directory

I don't have an issue moving master but if it's possible to do this without moving it I'd rather know. Is my setup possible?

Comment: In cluster computing all the configuration and setups in all the nodes should be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ramesh Maharjan  stated:

> ﻿﻿In cluster computing all the configuration and setups in all the nodes should be identical.

I have tested this on a setup where configuration and setup on all nodes is indentical and it now works.